# Choosing the Base for the $\pi$-adic Absolute Values on $\mathbb Q(i)$

Tags: number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

Let $\pi$ be a Gaussian prime. Like $p$ is the natural choice for the base in the $p$-adic absolute value $|x|_p = p^{-v_p(x)}$ due to the Product Formula, what is the natural choice for the base $c$ in the $\pi$-adic absolute values $|x|_\pi = c^{-v_\pi(x)}$ on $\mathbb Q(i)$, in each of the 3 cases (up to associates):

1. $\pi = 1 + i$
2. $\pi \equiv 3 \mod 4$ is a rational prime.
3. $\pi = x + iy$ or $x - iy$, where $p = (x + iy)(x - iy) \equiv 1 \mod 4$ is a rational prime?

Comment: My guess would be $|\pi|$ for the base. Actually in general, it does not matter what base $c > 1$ you use, as they all yield topologically equivalent norms

Comment: True, but there is a good reason to use $p$ as the base for the $p$-adic absolute value, so I figured perhaps there is a natural choice for other fields/values as well. What do you mean by $|\pi|$? Complex absolute value?

Comment: A natural choice is the one that makes the product of $|x|_{\pi}$ over all $\pi$ (including the infinite prime) one.

Comment: So what was meant by $|\pi|$ above?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Yes and no, as it doesn't fit into tower of fields (in $\Bbb{Q}$, $|3|_3=1/3$ while in $\Bbb{Q}[i]$ it would become $|3|_3 = 1/9$)

Comment: @reuns, I don't see what's wrong with that. The norm of $3$ in the rationals is $3$, but its norm in the Gaussians is $9$. Why should its $3$-adic valuation be the same in two different fields, when its norm isn't?

Comment: @GerryMyerson ? It is obvious, we are often interested in tower of ($p$-adic) fields in which case the natural choice will be different. With your choice, in $\Bbb{Q},|5|_5=1/5$ same as in $\Bbb{Q}(i), |5|_{2+i} = 1/5$.

Comment: There is some discussion of the problem in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/81814/normalised-absolute-values-on-p-adic-extensions, Johnny.

Comment: http://math.uchicago.edu/~may/REU2013/REUPapers/Ding.pdf may also be helpful.